# L-system rule for different plant types

Tags: botany

I have coded an implementation of L-systems (Lindenmayer systems) and would like to use it to generate realistic looking trees. Is there a reference list that shows which rules are most appropriate for different types of trees? For instance, which rules are best for an oak tree, which are best for cherry trees, etc.?

Comment: I d search for procedural trees... i.e. https://amp.reddit.com/r/proceduralgeneration/comments/6mpthc/procedural_tree_generation_incl_code/

Answer (score 1):

There are many good papers by Karl J. Niklas where he models tree growth. I'm not sure if he used L-systems in particular, but I'm sure his work can inform you about the 'rules'. You can find out more [here](http://labs.plantbio.cornell.edu/niklas/Research_Interests.html) and [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=karl%20j%20niklas&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).